# Trying to get a negative voltage for an op-amp

Tags: integrated-circuit, 741-opamp

I am trying to make a curcuit using an op-amp, but the op-amp needs a -Vs and +Vs voltage.  I don't know how to get the -Vs voltage.

I'm looking for a method to get a negative voltage so I can use it in my projects.

[image]

Comment: Take two batteries, each \$V\$ volt, connect them in series to get \$2V\$ volt. Call the middle node \$0V\$. Then one end you have \$+V\$ and the other end is \$-V\$. Something like this https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Batteries-in-series.png

Comment: Why do you need a "negative" voltage? The op-amp power supply terminals are labelled "+V" and "-V", but notice that there is no _ground_ pin on the op-amp. If you don't need the output of the op-amp to go as low as (or lower than) 0V, then you may be able to  power your circuit with a "single-ended power supply."

Comment: If your projects don't need a negative DC output, then your project also does not need a negative supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 53 years old 741 opamp was designed to use a +15V and a -15V supply but some of them work from +5V and -5V.
+5V and -5V is the same as +10V and 0V when the +input is biased with 2 series resistors to make +5V (half the supply voltage) and the input, output and negative feedback resistor are capacitor-coupled like this:

[image: opamps]

Comment: thank you for your time. how did you get -9v in the left side diagram(i mean practically ),because one of my output should be negative. So can you please explain to me the process of geting that negative -9v .

Comment: My opamp with a single polarity supply has its +input biased at half the supply voltage so that the +input and the opamp output can swing up and down with the capacitor coupled AC signals. You never posted a circuit and never said that you must use the opamp with plus and minus DC input signals. I never use the antique 741 opamp so my opamp works fine when powered from one 9V battery. Many modern opamps work fine from one 3V battery.